# how to print the sqlite values in a nice format with python?

Tags: python, sqlite

OK, so I am pulling some data from a sqlite database and I can't figure out how to properly format them when showing to the users...I'm using python 2.5.

```
    studentid = raw_input("Enter your student ID: ")
cur.execute('SELECT APP_DECISION FROM APP_STATUS WHERE STUDENTID = ?', (studentid,))
appdecision = cur.fetchall()
cur.execute('SELECT GRANT FROM FINAID WHERE STUDENTID = ?', (studentid,))
grant = cur.fetchall()
if (appdecision == 'ACCEPTED'):
print 'congratulations'
else:
    print 'sorry'

print (appdecision)
print (grant)
```

the results are getting printed like so,

```
Enter your student ID: 100006
[(u'ACCEPTED',)]
[(9500,)]
```

I want to be able to print it such as Accepted, and $9500....also. How do I check for the specific value so I can congratulate the users which have been accepted? 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print it as:

```
print (appdecision[0][0])
print (grant[0][0])
```

This is because `[(u'ACCEPTED',)]` is a list that contains a tuple that contains the string `"ACCEPTED"`. Similarly, you'll have to check for a value like this:

```
if appdecision[0][0] == "ACCEPTED":
    print "Congratulations!"
```